# Javascript API syntax help - const { uport, MNID }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, syntax

So while I was making my react native app, I tried to use an API from
https://github.com/uport-project/react-native-uport-connect and there is a syntax that I've yet to understand.

May I know what does `const { uport, MNID }` mean from this code

```
import configureUportConnect from 'react-native-uport-connect'

const { uport, MNID } = configureUportConnect({ 
  appName: 'uPort Demo', 
  appAddress: '2oeXufHGDpU51bfKBsZDdu7Je9weJ3r7sVG', 
  privateKey:'<PRIVATE_KEY>', 
})
```

Im quite new to this and this code is placed on a seperate js file and im trying to export `const { uport, MNID }` so I could use it in my Components and im not sure if it's a variable, object or some js syntax. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @Aeriel and welcome to SO. As you can see your question answered before. Actually, you can find many answers on this subject. So, feel free to read them. This question is probably going to be closed. If you don't get the answer after reading the previous ones you can drop a comment here by mentioning any commenter.

Comment: Got what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is called destructuring, and it means you are assigning your variables, not to the object that the function returns, but to the individual properties of that object, specifically the properties at the keys `uport` and `MNID`. The alternative syntax would be to say `const variableName = // etc...` and then you would access the properties like: `variableName.uport`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: I get it now. Thank you! Destructuring similar to like `const { varState } = this.state`